# How to stream data on different pages using one stream controller?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a singleton class to handle the stream. I need to use that `stream` on different pages.

Is it possible to do it using StreamController? (I didn't want to use `rxDart` plugin as of now)

**My Singleton class**

```
class ChatFieldService {
  static final ChatFieldService _singleton = ChatFieldService._internal();

  factory ChatFieldService() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  ChatFieldService._internal();

  final FirebaseService db = FirebaseService();

  String fromUserId;

  StreamController<List<ChatFieldModel>> _chatFields$ = StreamController<List<ChatFieldModel>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<ChatFieldModel>> get getChatFields {
    return _chatFields$.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }

  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  void initialize(String id) {
    fromUserId = id;
    _getAllChatFields();
  }

  void dispose() {
    streamSubscription?.cancel();
    _chatFields$?.close();
  }

  void _getAllChatFields() {
    streamSubscription = db.getAllChatField(fromUserId).listen((data) {
      if (!_chatFields$.isClosed) _chatFields$.sink.add(data);
    });
  }
}
```

**Dashboard Page**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chatFieldService.initialize(uid);
    oneSubscription = cfs.getChatFields.listen(allChatField);
    // Data is coming
  }
```

**Other pages**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    oneSubscription = cfs.getChatFields.listen(allChatField);
    // Never return values
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. I am glad you review my answer and give your feedback.

The issue here is when I listen to data on the other pages, It returns value only when changing. It means I cannot get initial values (already exist values in the controller) in the beginning level.

So, this is how I am getting initial values in the beginning.

**Create variable to store data**

```
  List<ChatFieldModel> _currentChatFields = [];

  List<ChatFieldModel> get currentChatFields => _currentChatFields;
```

**Add data to the array that same place add values to the controllerr**

```
  void _getAllChatFields() {
    if (fromUserId == null) fromUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    streamSubscription = db.getAllChatField(fromUserId).listen((data) {
      if (!_chatFields$.isClosed) {
        _currentChatFields = data; // here
        _getChatFields.add(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

**Other pages**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    allChatField(cfs.currentChatFields); // here
    oneSubscription = cfs.getChatFields.listen(allChatField);
    _analyticsService.openInboxScreen();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: You could use [RelaySubject](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ReplaySubject-class.html) for this purpose, but you should learn a bit reactive programming.

Comment: @Tokenyet Thanks. I am trying to do without plugins.